# Different lengths in overlapping plot

Tags: r, plot, line, overlap

Im having a problem with this plot guys, maybe you can work out a solution.

So im plotting September month and the income days of September in a Red line. And im plotting as well in the same graph October with the Octubre income days.

This is what im trying to make.

[image]

And this is what is happening in my R...

[image]

Here is the code im using to plot them together, but as they have different lenghts the plot overlap is really confusing.

```
plot(as.Date(Septiembre$Date), cumsum(Septiembre$TMM), type="l", col="red" )
par(new=TRUE)
plot(as.Date(Octubre$Date), cumsum(Octubre$TMM), type="l", col="green" )
```

And this is Septiembre and Octubre data.

```
> Septiembre$Date
[1] "2015-09-24" "2015-09-26"
> Septiembre$TMM
[1] 720 540
> Octubre$Date
[1] "2015-10-01" "2015-10-03" "2015-10-09" "2015-10-10" "2015-10-11"
> Octubre$TMM
[1] 400 540 360 720 360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you calculate the x and y ranges, then you can make the proper window size.

```
## Ranges
xlim <- range(as.Date(Septiembre$Date), as.Date(Octubre$Date))
ylim <- range(0, sapply(list(Septiembre$TMM, Octubre$TMM), cumsum))

## Make the plot
plot(as.Date(Septiembre$Date), cumsum(Septiembre$TMM), type="l", col="red",
     xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)
points(as.Date(Octubre$Date), cumsum(Octubre$TMM), type="l", col="green" )
```

I'm not sure if that is the range you are looking for.  Here is another possibility, where the dates are converted to integers and normalized to start from 0 in each case.

```
## Normalize the date data
dateRanges <- lapply(list(Septiembre$Date, Octubre$Date), function(x) {
    res <- as.integer(as.Date(x))
    res - res[1]
})

xlim <- c(0, max(unlist(dateRanges)))
ylim <- range(0, sapply(list(Septiembre$TMM, Octubre$TMM), cumsum))

## Make the plot
plot(dateRanges[[1]], cumsum(Septiembre$TMM), type="l", col="red",
     xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, xaxt='n', xlab="Date", ylab="")
par(new=TRUE)
plot(dateRanges[[2]], cumsum(Octubre$TMM), type="l", col="green",
     xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, axes = FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thats awesome thanks. Do you have any idea how could I possibly set the x axis with the Dates? from the 1st till the 31st.

Comment: independently of the month name, set the x axis from 1st till 31st

Comment: if you want the full range from 1 to 31, the `xlim` should be adjusted to go from `c(0, 30)` (since the dates are normalized to start at 0).  To add some tick marks and labels, you could use `axis(1, 0:30, labels=1:31)`

Comment: you're right. It was that simple! Thanks a lot bunk, you really helped me out!!